# ASP.NET web garden - max worker threads

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm investigating some performance improvements that can be made to our web server and ASP.NET application. [This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821268) page contains a few things that we can do.

We currently have two worker processes running as a garden.  Do each of these worker processes have their own ASP.NET threadpool?  Or do both of these worker processes share a single threadpool and the max number of worker threads is shared across these processes?

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2006/03/14/thoughts-on-application-pools-running-out-of-threads.aspx) post seems to suggest that the two processes share a common ASP.NET threadpool.

> All w3wp.exe threads do is take
>   requests from HTTP.SYS queue, process
>   it, and hand the request to
>   ASPNET_ISAPI.DLL, who then deposits
>   those requests into the ASP.Net
>   request queue, and the ASP.Net threads
>   service that queue.

But [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1162420.aspx) post suggests that each worker process contains their own ASP.NET threadpool.

> Each process (w3wp.exe) has its own
>   CLR thread pool which has the
>   configured maxworkerthreads value (20
>   default).

Which is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each worker process will have its own thread pool and separate ASP.NET request queue.

Processes can't really share threads, threads run in the context of a single process.